# converting vob files to swf and flv

Tags: flash, video, vob

I have a .vob file and I am trying to change it to .swf and .flv for my website. I found lots of open source software that can convert to flash.

The only thing is that, i want my final flash files to be not more than 50KB. I am using this software:

http://www.rersoft.com/dvd-vob-file/convert-vob-to-swf.html

i am not sure of the standard websize for flash.

my .vob size is: 267,000KB.

thanks for your feedbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't like your video software is either open source or free. You should contact the vendor on how to do that if you own that particular package.

Many packages allow you to set the output size and automatically adjust the settings to that. You could also try reducing the resolution and size until you get down to 50kb.

Another solution would be to start with Windows Movie Maker, save your filed down to 50kb using the "Best Fit to Size" option, then import it into your software and convert it to flash.

Answer (score 0):

VOB file comes from DVD folder itself. Some vob files can be protected. You need to remove the protection before converting VOB to other format.